# Sliding image with fixed Logo in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an application in swift and in the landing page,I want to do something like [This](http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/UIPageViewController-Tutorial-Screen.jpg).I want to slide my images with those texts,but the logo and the buttons will remain in the same place.Someone asked this type of solution in this site in a comment,but didn't get any solution.So can someone tell me how to do this?I am stuck here

Comment: I am asking for swift,not objective-c

Comment: You can do translation from Objective-C to Swift. Else, the topic gave you the main component to use: `UIPageViewController`, and I'm sure that you can find tutorial in Swift about it. Your main issue was that you didn't know what kind of object use, and you've got your answer now. You can start digging.

Comment: Yes that will need some digging.Thanks btw for giving the idea of translation